# Magento 2 custom php library is not working

Tags: magento2, api, third-party-module

I want to add custom php API library under `vendor` folder and I have added the following folder and files under vendor folder.

1. magento2_root>vendor/abc/
2. magento2_root>vendor/abc/abc_php/
3. magento2_root>vendor/abc/abc_php/composer.json
4. magento2_root>vendor/abc/abc_php/lib/
5. magento2_root>vendor/abc/abc_php/lib/Test.php

> magento2_root>vendor/abc/abc_php/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "abc/abc_php",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "ABC PHP Client Library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Custom Author",
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CustomApi\\": "lib"
        }
    }
}
```

> magento2_root>vendor/abc/abc_php/lib/Test.php

```
<?php
    

namespace CustomApi;

class Test
{
    public function customMethod(){
    return "abc";
    }
}
```

When I include this in constructor like following

```
public function __construct(
...
\CustomApi\Test $testApi,
...
){
// do some logic
}
```

It gives me `Class CustomApi\Test does not exist` error.

**PS :** I have recompiled the composer by using `composer dumpautoload` command. It does not generate autoload script in autoload_psr4.php under `vendor/composer` folder.

Can anyone tell me that what I did wrong ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging whole day continuously, finally I found the solution.

**Solution 1** : Add you custom library folder in magento root `composer.json` like mention below

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "CustomApi\\": "abc/abc_php/lib" my custom library code
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
```

And recompile the composer by using `composer dumpautoload`

**Solution 2** : Using Packagist. Process is given below

1. Add your library code to `git repository` and release.
2. Add this repository code to  `http://packagist.org/`
3. install this library via composer directly by command `composer
   require abc/abc_php "1.0.0"`

For example, You can check with [braintree on git](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php) and [braintree on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/braintree/braintree_php).